# Show Expired data using DateAdd function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to show the data that is already expired or the data that is going to expire in one month.  I have 2 columns of dates that we use for different reasons and i want to check both columns.  Example:

```
ProductName   Date1          Date2
xyz           5/8/2015       9/7/2015 
mlk           8/2/2015       5/3/2016
gml           4/4/2017        7/8/2017
mmm           5/8/2016        7/30/2015
```

desired results:

```
 ProductName   Date1          Date2
    xyz           5/8/2015       9/7/2015 
    mlk           8/2/2015       5/3/2016
    mmm           5/8/2016        7/30/2015
```

I want to show xyz because Date1 has already expired.
I want to show mlk because Date1 is about to expire in one month.
I want to show mmm because Date2 is about to expire in one month.
Please help.  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you just want to know when `Date1` or `Date2` are less than one month from today. Using `DATEADD`, we can get the date one month on from today, then compare that using `<`:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE Date1 < DATEADD(mm, 1, GETDATE())
OR Date2 < DATEADD(mm, 1, GETDATE())
```